# ASP.net core3.1 mvc data display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-core

I am new in APS.Net core MVC and want to display database data on a web page. I have created a Model class similar to the database table as shown in the code below:

```
 public class Customer
{   [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
 }
```

and a Controller class :

```
 public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public CustomersController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    // Get Data 
    public  async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _db.Customers.ToListAsync());
        }
    }
```

and a view page

```
 @model IEnumerable<Customers>

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Customers List";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Records</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
            </th>  
     </tr>
    </thead>
```

When I run the application and navigate to the page  the following message appears:

> **A database operation failed while processing the request.
>   InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to
>   type 'System.Int32'.**
>
> Applying existing migrations for ApplicationDbContext may resolve this
>   issue There are migrations for ApplicationDbContext that have not been
>   applied to the database
>
> 20200305172409_Customers Apply Migrations
>
> In Visual Studio, you can use the Package Manager Console to apply
>   pending migrations to the database:
>
> PM> Update-Database Alternatively, you can apply pending migrations
>   from a command prompt at your project directory:
>
> > dotnet ef database update

I tried to add-migration and update-database but the following message appears in the Package Manager Console:

> Failed executing DbCommand (224ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',
>   CommandTimeout='30'] CREATE TABLE [Customers] ( There is already an
>   object named 'Customers' in the database.

The connection service in startup.cs is as default :

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Thats has nothing to do with asp.net mvc showing - it has all to do with your database object not being compatible with the definition of the field in the database.

Comment: Your ID that you have as int here is probably defined as BigInt in sql db

Comment: @Nikki9696 Or maybe `Age` ? or even both ! It's a guessing game without seeing his DB structure.

Comment: Please share your table design in your database.It seems that you need to change your the type from bigint to int in your database.

Comment: Thank you guys the problem was that I defined the Id as BigInt in DB